# Trying to build devcon tool

Tags: visual-studio, winapi

I'm trying to build this tool "https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/main/setup/devcon" but I got this error:

> "Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error MSB8020 The build tools for WindowsApplicationForDrivers10.0
> (Platform Toolset = 'WindowsApplicationForDrivers10.0') cannot be
> found. To build using the WindowsApplicationForDrivers10.0 build
> tools, please install WindowsApplicationForDrivers10.0 build tools.
> Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by
> selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then
> selecting "Retarget solution"

I installed WDK.

Comment: Have you tried what the error tells you? Like upgrade VS and retarget solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Device Console (DevCon) Tool" sample was last updated 4 years ago and is configured for an older version of the WDK.

If you have Visual Studio 2022 and followed the instructions at "[Download the Windows Driver Kit (WDK)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk)", then retarget the solution.

Alternatively install VS 2019 and the older WDK. See the instructions at "[Other WDK downloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/other-wdk-downloads)".